# Apache Nifi - create a new pipeline using API

Tags: apache-nifi

Can we create a new pipeline using Apache Nifi API without using the GUI? If yes, then please let me know the steps for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response to your question is yes, you can use:

- NiFi API.
- NiFi CLI from version 1.6.
- NiPyApi python client thanks to @chaffelson

You can find the documentation here:
https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-toolkit/nifi-toolkit-cli
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

You can also search in the Hortonworks page, there is a lot of contain that can be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with Python, there is also a community Python client for NiFi.
https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi

And a quick introduction here:
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/167364/nifi-sdlc-automation-in-python-with-nipyapi-part-1.html

note: I am the primary author.

Comment: Thank you :) That is very kind!